# TYPO3 News Extension list image size/position

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am using the [news](https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news) extension in TYPO3 6.2.14.

Two things:

1) How do I change the image size in the news list view? I need the images here to be 300px wide yet the settings only have the option for max width. Setting maxWidth to 300 gives me variable image widths between 150 and 200 at the moment.

2) I need the list view images to be above their headers. I have edited the List.html file but I don't know how to make the extension use my file instead of the default.

Comment: Off-topic, but you are aware that 6.2.14 contains [severe security issues](https://typo3.org/teams/security/security-bulletins/typo3-core/typo3-core-sa-2016-013/)?

Comment: @StephenKing I know, but it's not my installation so I can't change it. Love your books by the way ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can change the `<f:image>` in the Partials/FalMediaImage.html to use width and height. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Image.html). Or you can define the correct max width and a bigger max height and upload big images.

2) You can do it in TypoScript as it is in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/Start/Index.html).

```
plugin.tx_news {
        view {
                templateRootPaths >
                templateRootPaths {
                        0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Templates/
                        1 = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Templates/
                }
                partialRootPaths >
                partialRootPaths {
                        0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Partials/
                        1 = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Partials/
                }
                layoutRootPaths >
                layoutRootPaths {
                        0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Layouts/
                        1 = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Layouts/
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: I had that typoscript already, the problem was a lowercase L on my 'List' folder.  It now shows my new page as 'Oops, an error occurred!' with the log saying "Could not analyse class:GeorgRinger\News\ViewHelpers\ExcludeDisplayedNewsViewHelper maybe not loaded or no autoloader?" Any idea what this means?

Comment: I am not sure, what version of news do you use? Try to use the latest stabil version. Clear all cache in Install Tool.

Comment: Turns out it was because I was using a new version of List.html with an old version of the extension. But thanks for your help!

Comment: @user500665: Sorry that it took time, I did not check your comment in time. If the answer helped with the f:image, could you pls accept it?